# When calling list_append on Amazon DynamoDB, the newly added items get inserted twice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The attribute in Amazon DynamoDB has the type List of Strings (`LS`). When updating the attribute with `list_append` it duplicates the item I would like to add. The log from the SDK:

```
    updateItem({
     TableName: 'dynamodb-table',
     Key: { id: { S: 'ids' } },
     UpdateExpression: 'SET #ids = list_append(#ids, :new_ids)',
     ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#ids': 'list_ids' },
     ExpressionAttributeValues: {
       ':new_ids': { L: [ { S: 'id3' }, [length]: 1 ] }
       }
     })
```

I've tried `:new_ids` as first and second argument. Same result. This basically turns `['id1', id2]` into `['id1', id2, id3, id3]`. While I am expecting `['id1', id2, id3]`

Answer (score 0):

The SET command you did is correct, and should have added the new item 'id3' exactly once. Could it be you are running this UpdateItem request twice for some reason?

By the way, a comment on your first sentence: DynamoDB does not have a "List of Strings" (LS) type. It's just a "List" (L). A list may contain any type of objects - not just strings. It can even be empty. This is unlike a Set Of Strings (SS) which can only contains strings and cannot be empty.

Comment: Hi Nadav, thanks for the clarification wrt. Lists. Looking into the logs, I see the sdk log exactly once. My solution right now is, that I handle it on the application side and update the whole list. The list itself is not growing too big.